# I've burned my stainless steel macchinetta. Is it still safe for use?

Tags: equipment, moka

I accidentally put my macchinetta on the stove with no water in it. A few minutes have passed until I realized what I have done, and in the mean time the pot has overheated, started to smell quite badly, and it's bottom has received a (permanent?) brownish hue.

The pot is stainless steel (bialetti [venus](http://www.bialetti.com/coffee/stovetop/stainless-pots/venus-c-1_7_21_35.html?zenid=g2b85m8gg9kq8r185pa8a2q2l0) model), but I don't know what the inner coating is made of. In terms of toxicity, is it safe to continue using it?

Comment: Hi TheShked, this is something you couldn't know, but we have a sister site which is specifically about coffee, and we send questions about coffee over to them because there you tend to get the better answers. So I am moving your question - this is not a sign you have done anything wrong though. And the answer moves along automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly okay to overheat stainless steel.

You can clean it by boiling soap water in it. [Here's a link](https://www.hunker.com/12000449/how-to-remove-a-stain-in-an-overheated-stainless-steel-pan)

You should replace the seal (the seal should be replaced ever so often anyways).

Comment: thanks, do you have any idea if the pot has any inner coating from other materials?

Comment: @TheShked, the details show it's stainless steel.