# Is it safe to use a moka pot after coffee was burnt in it without water?

Tags: moka, equipment

I accidentally put my aluminum moka pot on the stove without any water in it, and noticed it after the coffee inside started burning. The bottom of the is a bit burnt on the surface, but the gasket inside looks ok.

Similar questions:

1. [Similar problem, not as serious](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/accidentially-put-aluminum-moka-pot-on-stove-without-water-is-it-still-usabl)
2. [Same problem, different pot material](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/ive-burned-my-stainless-steel-macchinetta-is-it-still-safe-for-use)

Comment: I think the first link should already answer your question - even if you heated the Moka more .

Comment: @Stephie the difference is, that in the first link, the water was in the pot, but in the top part, not in the bottom one. Mine was empty. And the coffee in mine was burnt.

Comment: Mine (see chat link in my answer) was also empty and smoking. I think it’s a duplicate (still far away from any critical temperature, you may need to replace the gasket), but won’t mod-hammer just now.

Comment: @Stephie after reading the chat link, it seems like almost the same situation, I guess it can be flagged as a duplicate